# Are there screwdrivers that can hold an M1 slotted screw during insertion without being magnetic?

Tags: screws, screwdriver

I need to be able to insert an M1x2 slotted screw into a tapped hole upside down, and critically without dropping the screw. That rules out magnetic headed screwdrivers unless I can't find anything else.

I've seen some screwdriver designs such as this one from [Wiha Tools](https://cdn.wihatoolsus.com/pdfs/WihaScrewdriversCatalog.pdf) (see p9) which would in principle work for larger screws, but apparently not M1:

[image: Wiha screw holding screwdriver]

I've got two problems:

- I can't seem to find one small enough to work with M1 screws
- I don't know the "standard term" used to describe these screwdrivers. I've seen "gripping screwdriver", "screw holding screwdriver" and others.

I think there must be some watchmaker's screwdriver that would work, but I can't seem to find any. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand - what is it about your requirements that rules out magnetic screwdrivers?

Comment: Quite simply, I can't guarantee that the screw will be a magnetic material. It's for vacuum use use where [cold welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding) can become a problem. We avoid using the same material for screws as we do for the thread.

Comment: there are some that have a spring loaded center section (2 types I know of) one the spring load makes an almost Phillips looking bit when not in a slot the center holds the screw in place while starting. the second is 2 pieces of metal that spread to hold the screw I have seen these in much smaller sizes but not sure about M1. both are for starting  not for driving.

Comment: @EdBeal, those sound promising. Do you know any specific models I could look at?

Comment: Here is a link to 1 type that may be small enough look for [screw starter](https://www.zoro.com/vaco-screw-hold-screwdriver-set-slotted-3-pc-sk234/i/G2070957/?gclid=CICvyKq-sNICFQx6fgod1OQAxw) here is a link to the other type [screw starter x](https://www.zoro.com/proto-double-screw-startr-6-14-phillips-slot-j9866/i/G1522132/?gclid=CLro8Oq-sNICFQtofgod-HYAcw). the second may be two large but provides an idea of what I was talking about. I also found this [micro starter](http://www.micromark.com/Micro-Screw-Starter-for-Slotted-Screws?gclid=CM705KO_sNICFQ5EfgodGCMDyA) hope these examples help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Instead of buying those tools, I just got [this bigger one](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/screwdrivers/0547975/) and used a sander to shim off some of the metal. It was a quick and dirty hack but it worked.

Comment: Unless that's the smallest one in that line of tools, you could post your hack as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by buying [as small a gripping screwdriver as I could find](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/screwdrivers/0547975/), and sanding it down to fit the slot on my M1 screw:

[image: Gripping screwdriver with M1 screw]

Thanks for your help.